# What is the difference between nginx and nginx:alpine?

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux, debian-based

My goal is to understand why is there a `nginx` image and also `nginx:alpine` image.

What I know:

1. `nginx` is larger, 52.79 MB.
2. `nginx` uses `debian:bullseye-slim`.
3. `nginx:alpine` is smaller, 9.51 MB.
4. `nginx:alpine` uses `alpine`.
5. both images can run static html just fine `docker run -p 8080:80 -v ${PWD}:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:alpine`

I cannot wrap my head around why the default image uses `debian:bullseye-slim` rather than `alpine`.